# Cordova | Cannot download proguard-base.jar when trying to emulate android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to run `cordova emulate android` but I am getting this error. I have installed `gradle`, and I also configured `$ANDROID_HOME` path variable.

**The error message:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not download proguard-base.jar (net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:5.3.3)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/5.3.3/proguard-base-5.3.3.jar'.
  >   Response 304: Not Modified has no content!

How can I solve this error?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, but in context of setting up a flutter project.

Comment: @PrateekKhandelwal turns out my issue was due to my ISP blocking the URL in question. I don't know why they booked it. I tried with a different internet connection and it worked fine!. I suggest you use a different internet connection

Comment: You are correct, apparently my ISP had also blocked this URL.

Comment: @PrateekKhandelwal yeah. I've added it as an answer now to help anyone else who faces the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my ISP had blocked the URL in question. You should try with a different connection if this affects you too.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good way to clean up your caches, delete all the contents of the C:\Users\wqt.gradle\caches folder, and open the IDE from a new one.
[image]